# R programming - answer function

Tags: r

I am very new to R programming, I keep getting this error despite loading all the packages.
Can anyone guide me - The error is as follows:-
Error in answer("greater than 1") : could not find function "answer"

Comment: Somewhere your code has the line `answer("greater than 1")` and `answer()` is not a function from any of the packages you have loaded. Do you know what package it's supposed to be from? Did you use `library(that_package)` to load in your current R session?

Comment: Welcome to SO, NamrataThaivalappil! Please realize that without seeing what you are trying to do, there is almost nothing we can do. Questions on SO (and especially within the [tag:r] tag) do much better when the question is reproducible, providing sample data (if needed), code attempted, the literal text of errors/warnings (and *where* they occur in the code), and the expected output. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info for tips on asking questions *well*, then come back and [edit] your question to add content. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @GregorThomas, thank you for responding, I realized that I had made a silly mistake, I tried deleting the question I posted but couldn't. Turned out that I hadn't assigned any value to the function R and hence wasn't able to execute it.

Comment: If you look at the bottom of the question in the line with `Share  Edit  ...` there should be a `Delete` option.